# Python - Ventana pop up con mensaje de espera. Qt, Pyside

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyqt4, pyside

Tengo un programa con interface hecho con Qt, Pyside.

Después de completar los campos de la interface el programa realiza unas acciones que tardan un tiempo.

Lo que me gustaría es poner una ventana pop up con un mensaje y que no deje al usuario tocar nada del programa y cuando termine el programa de realizar sus acciones que le aparezca otra ventana con un boton cerrar. Esta ventana con el boton cerrar ya la tengo.

**Lo que necesito es saber cómo puedo abrir una ventana pop up que se cierre sola al terminar el proceso y que no deje al usuario tocar nada mientras está abierta.**
He visto los QProgressDialog y los QProgressBar, pero quiero algo muy simple que solamente muestre un mensaje.

```
def funcion_que_tarda_un_minuto():
    ...
    ...
    #aquí abrir la ventana pop up con un mensaje "espera mientras se realizan los cálculos" y que no deje al usuario hacer nada en el programa

    #Una vez terminados los cálculos, esta ventana se cierra sola y aparece al instante otra con:
    self.msgBox = QMessageBox
    self.msgBox = setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
    self.msgBox = setText("Proceso finalizado")
    self.retval = self.msgBox.exec_()
```

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Un proceso que demora un minuto no debe ejecutarse en el hilo de la GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es bastante complicado: debes procesar la información en otro hilo o proceso.
Con hilos, puedes ocupar señales para comunicar el término de proceso.

Un buen punto de partida es el [ejemplo mandelbrot](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/threads/mandelbrot.py):

```
def función_que_tarda_un_minuto():
    # …
    return True

class Trabajador(QThread):
    terminado = pyqtSignal()
    # …
    def run(self):
        # esto se ejecuta en otro hilo
        función_que_tarda_un_minuto()
        self.terminado.emit()

class MiWidget(QWidget):
    # …
    def desplegar_cuadro_terminado(self):
        msg_box = QMessageBox()
        # …
        msg_box.exec_()

    def correr_cálculos(self):
        trabajador = Trabajador()
        trabajador.terminado.connect(self.desplegar_cuadro_terminado)
        trabajador.start()
```

Comment: Felipe, bienvenido a SOes. Si pudieras añadir un breve ejemplo de hilos en python, creo que tu respuesta quedaria excelente.